# Android NDK -Error while compiling Library

Tags: android, android-ndk

I found [this](https://github.com/VladimirKulyk/SoundTouch-Android) on GitHub which is a wrapper for the great SoundTouch C++ library.

I'm completely new to NDK though, so would any of you kindly explain to me how to set it up correctly?

I downloaded the zip from GitHub and copied the directories into my existing project. Still, it couldn't find the native C++ functions.

I tried compiling the library using `ndk-build` but I got two errors. This is my terminal log:

```
Android NDK: APP_PLATFORM not set. Defaulting to minimum supported version android-14.    
Android NDK: WARNING:/home/daniele/AndroidStudioProjects/Chords2/app/jni/Android.mk:soundtouch: non-system libraries in linker flags: -lgcc    
Android NDK:     This is likely to result in incorrect builds. Try using LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES    
Android NDK:     or LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES instead to list the library dependencies of the    
Android NDK:     current module    
Android NDK: WARNING:/home/daniele/AndroidStudioProjects/Chords2/app/jni/Android.mk:soundtouch: non-system libraries in linker flags: -lgcc    
Android NDK:     This is likely to result in incorrect builds. Try using LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES    
Android NDK:     or LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES instead to list the library dependencies of the    
Android NDK:     current module    
[armeabi-v7a] Compile++ thumb: soundtouch <= soundtouch-jni.cpp
[armeabi-v7a] Compile++ thumb: soundtouch <= AAFilter.cpp
[armeabi-v7a] Compile++ thumb: soundtouch <= FIFOSampleBuffer.cpp
[armeabi-v7a] Compile++ thumb: soundtouch <= FIRFilter.cpp
[armeabi-v7a] Compile++ thumb: soundtouch <= cpu_detect_x86.cpp
[armeabi-v7a] Compile++ thumb: soundtouch <= RateTransposer.cpp
[armeabi-v7a] Compile++ thumb: soundtouch <= SoundTouch.cpp
[armeabi-v7a] Compile++ thumb: soundtouch <= TDStretch.cpp
[armeabi-v7a] Compile++ thumb: soundtouch <= BPMDetect.cpp
[armeabi-v7a] Compile++ thumb: soundtouch <= PeakFinder.cpp
[armeabi-v7a] SharedLibrary  : libsoundtouch.so
[armeabi-v7a] Install        : libsoundtouch.so => libs/armeabi-v7a/libsoundtouch.so
[armeabi] Compile++ thumb: soundtouch <= soundtouch-jni.cpp
/home/daniele/AndroidStudioProjects/Chords2/app/jni/soundtouch-jni.cpp:133:2: error: 
      no matching function for call to 'convertInput16'
        convertInput16(ar, fBufferIn, BUFF_SIZE);
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/daniele/AndroidStudioProjects/Chords2/app/jni/soundtouch-jni.cpp:58:13: note: 
      candidate function not viable: no known conversion from
      'soundtouch::SAMPLETYPE *' (aka 'short *') to 'float *' for 2nd argument
static void convertInput16(jbyte*, float*, int);
            ^
/home/daniele/AndroidStudioProjects/Chords2/app/jni/soundtouch-jni.cpp:210:16: error: 
      no matching function for call to 'write'
                processed += write(fBufferIn, fBufferOut, nSamples * cha...
                             ^~~~~
/home/daniele/AndroidStudioProjects/Chords2/app/jni/soundtouch-jni.cpp:56:12: note: 
      candidate function not viable: no known conversion from
      'soundtouch::SAMPLETYPE *' (aka 'short *') to 'const float *' for 1st
      argument
static int write(const float*, queue<signed char>*, int, int);
           ^
2 errors generated.
make: *** [/home/daniele/AndroidStudioProjects/Chords2/app/obj/local/armeabi/objs/soundtouch/soundtouch-jni.o] Error 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hi you must compile library.
I suggest you use:
 Linux ubuntu 
 NDK 14rb
First update your Linux with the following commands

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Set NDK Environment Variable:

```
export ANDROID_NDK=~/Desktop/ndk-folder
export NDK_ROOT=$ANDROID_NDK
export PATH=${PATH}:${ANDROID_NDK}
```

Then open the terminal and go to the jni folder in the project folder.
To compile the library just enter the following command:

```
ndk-build
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I should have mentioned it before. I'm on linux. Should the ndk-build command be followed from something else?

Comment: by linux terminal you can send ndk-build command (before it, you must set ndk Environment Variables)

Comment: sorry for keeping asking. But how do I do it? If I try to run ndk-build I get a command not found error

Comment: If I downloaded the NDK directly from Android Studio, where will I find it?

Comment: in sdk folder may called ndk-bundle

Comment: Also where do I put the "export" code you mentioned? in terminal?

Comment: ok I did it, but when going to the jni folder and entering ndk-build I still get "ndk-build: command not found"

Comment: use one terminal for doing this, first add env variable then don't close terminal and go to jni folder and type ndk-build, Note that you You must specify the ndk folder address in first export that I placed my ndk folder in desktop

Comment: ok It started compiling but then stopped because of some errors. Would you have a look at the updated question please

Answer (score 1):

Use NDK 14 only. NDK 15 and 16 aren't good enough to use for NDK building. They have got issues.
Get it from https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/older_releases.html and in Project Setting change to the extracted location of NDK 14. It will resolve the issues related to NDK.